# Как создать дочернюю тему для opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.0

Есть сайт на Opencart, есть тема, хочу создать дочернюю для кастомизации, что нужно сделать для этого, как указать что новая тема является дочерней. Буду рад ссылкам на любую документацию в этом направлении, так как ничего не нашел

Answer (score 3):

Дочерних тем в том понимании как это сделано в WordPress'е нет. Да и все расширения Opencart работают только с темой по умолчанию, а не как у wp.

Но чтобы можно было модифицировать темы придумали расширение **vQmod** (более подробно сможете найти в гугле, по нему много уроков). Через это расширение вы можете модифицировать практически всё и не боятся при обновлении темы.

**Как это выглядит.** Например нам нужно модифицировать шаблон методов оплаты:

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl">
  <operation>
     <search><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>]]></search>
     <add position="before"><![CDATA[
         <?php if($shipping_method['code'] == "onedel"):?>
             <?php echo $onedel_content;?>
         <?php endif;?>
     ]]></add>
  </operation>
</file>
```

Расширение найдет в шаблоне `catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl` строку `<?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>` и ДО неё добавит код:

```
<?php if($shipping_method['code'] == "onedel"):?>
  <?php echo $onedel_content;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

После этого обновляем кеш модификатор и всё.

Эти изменения буду проходить "на лету", без изменения самого файла шаблона:

> Вместо внесения изменений в основные файлы напрямую, изменения
>   создаются как XML скрипты поиска/замены. Эти файлы скриптов
>   обрабатываются во время загрузки страницы, как отдельный файл движка
>   "исходник" загруженный функциями php "include" или "require". Файл
>   исходник изменяется с учетом файла скрипта, и сохраняются во временный
>   файл. Потом временный файл заменяет исходный во вермя выполнения.
>   Оригинальный файл никогда не меняется. В результате "виртуальные"
>   изменения в движке происходят во время выполнения без существенных
>   изменений файлов ядра.

**Проблемы.** Расширение работает только c PHP файлами. Модифицировать CSS и JS он не умеет. Но в принципе это можно решить, путём создания необходимого css/js файла и подключения его через vQmod.

Comment: Александр спасибо большое за очень подробный ответ